# Is there any way to disable OR password protect my iPhone to prevent someone from turning it off?

Tags: iphone, ios, password, jailbreak

If my phone is stolen, I would think the first thing a thief would do is turn it off.  Is there any way to disable or password protect this via settings (which I doubt) OR a cydia tweak?

Answer (score 2):

If you've jailbroken your phone, try either [iGotYa](http://igotya.com) or [iCaughtYou Pro](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=icaughtuproDp). They offer the best protection against theft without using a commercial MDM system, in my opinion.

[PowerGuard](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=powerguardDp) will provide the power feature you want, but it won't protect the phone from being placed in DFU mode. Still, a combination of both PowerGuard and one of the above apps is better than nothing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

This won't prevent powering it off, but, if you've upgraded to iOS7:

> With Find My iPhone turned on in iOS 7, your Apple ID and password will be always be required before anyone can:
>
> - **Turn off Find My iPhone on your device.**
> - **Erase your device.**
> - **Reactivate and use your device.**
>
> There is nothing you need to do except to keep Find My iPhone turned on and remember
>   your Apple ID and password.

From a device security perspective, I think this would accomplish the same thing by rendering your device useless to anyone who steals or finds it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not worried about DFU mode since I would guess a majority of thieves wouldn't even know what DFU mode is.  It's basically the first few hours that are crucial once it's stolen. Once the battery runs out then there's  less of a chance.

Comment: It probably doesn't protect against holding down the Lock and Home button at the same time (hard-reboot) either.